# javascript (google apps script) declaring variables

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have written a code. To run the code I have declared quite a few variables. Now that I finished, I realised that I did not have to declare the variables as I can call on what the variable is supposed to call for directly within the function.

Example:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
  sheet.appendRow(date);
}
```

I could have not declared date and written this:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
}
```

Which of those is considered best practice and better for performance of app?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you don’t need that variable. Similarly, you don’t need variables for `new Date()`, `"GMT"` or `"dd-MMM-yyyy"`. You actually don’t need any of those variables, as you could’ve written `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().appendRow(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"));`.

Comment: Indeed. But is it considered good practice in terms of writing code and efficiency of code calculation?

Comment: The efficiency won’t be different. Declaring a variable comes with a minuscule cost in execution time. I’m not sure about whether avoiding variables like this is best practice. I always try to avoid unnecessary ones.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, thanks. But I wonder what is the definition of an unnecessary variable?

Comment: I’d say, a variable is unnecessary, if it’s only used once, or if it’s only used in one location and holds a fixed value. In your case, all variables would only be used once. In a case like `const keys = Object.keys(array); otherArray.map((value) => keys.something(value));`, `keys` is only in one location, but it’s used multiple times. Replacing `keys` by `Object.keys(array)` would recreate the array with `Object.keys(array)` every single iteration of `.map`, so using a variable is more performant.

Comment: Though, several aspects of this are debatable and a matter of taste. For example, I often try to avoid fixed values, e.g. `let color = "hsl(120, 100%, ${luminosity + 50})";` — what is `120`; why is `50` added; what does all this mean? Instead, `const greenHue = 120, luminosityOffset = 50;` might be much clearer. But I do try to avoid variables for “intermediate” values like `ss` and `sheet` in your example. But then again, these variables might make debugging easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect on performance will be negligible. You should write it the way that is most readable. In your case that is debatable, but I like declaring the `date` variable since it makes the subsequent line much shorter and less overwhelming.

A case where it could affect performance would be if you were consuming the date in multiple locations. Then, you would want to declare a variable. For example...

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
  somethingElse(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"));
}
```

Aside from violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), the above hurts performance because you are doing the work twice (creating a Date object and formatting it).

In summary, if you are only consuming the value once, you don't need to make it a variable, but you should if it improves readability.